# How to define a function inside a function and call it from outside?

Tags: javascript, signalr

I've started learning `JavaScript` and this problem blocked me. please look at this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // How to define some functions here to call from below script?
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
    gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function(event) {
        var carousel = document.getElementById("mediaCarousel");
        var index = carousel.currentIndex;
        // how to pass this index to a function above?
};
</script>
```

in the first script I try to connect to the server. in the second script, user can select an image.

I want to pass the `index` from second script to a function inside the first one to send it to the server.

How can I define a function in first one and how to call it? thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell which function should be called first according to your requirement?

Comment: @Nirzar when the page gets loaded, first function connects to the server and stays connected.. I need to pass values to server when user selects something

Comment: Then you can specify the index as a global variable and at the connection you can check if it has value or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<script>
    var newFunction = undefined;

    $(function () {
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // How to define some functions here to call from below script?
            newFunction = function(index){
                // Your function processing.
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
    gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function(event) {
        var carousel = document.getElementById("mediaCarousel");
        var index = carousel.currentIndex;
        // how to pass this index to a function above?
        if(newFunction) newFunction(index);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example below. Define your function in the `connection.done` callback function, then call the function when a selection has changed.

```js
$(function() {
  // Start the connection.
  $(window).load(function() {

    // We'll define our function here
    postConnectFunction = function(index) {
      console.log('You selected', index)
    }

  });
});

// When something is changed we'll call the function above
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
  if (postConnectFunction) {
    postConnectFunction(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @BrettDeWoody

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the function to an outer-scoped reference, like so:

```
var functionReference = undefined;
$(function() {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        functionReference = function () { /* ... */ };
    });
});

// You could then check if the function is set later, and invoke it:
if (functionReference) {
    functionReference(index);
}
```

However, a better way to handle this sort of problem that you are presenting would be to set the event handler instead of passing around a function reference:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    // Obtain a reference to the carousel element:
    var carousel = document.getElementById("mediaCarousel");

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        window.gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function (event) {
            // Call your handler function
            handleBoardSelectionChange(carousel.currentIndex);
        };
    });

    // We are separating and naming this function so that the logic
    // above remains concise and readable, if we kept all of the
    // functions of this nature anonymous it would have been harder to
    // follow the code due to length and scope depth.
    function handleBoardSelectionChange(index) {
        // Do your work here
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function(event) {
    // Indicate to the user that we are not ready yet.
    // (Do whatever is sensible here, maybe doing nothing is better?)
    alert('Not connected yet, please wait...');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var innerfunc;
    $(function () {
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // How to define some functions here to call from below script?
              innerfunc = function(index) {
                  console.log('here is my index: ' + index);
              };

        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
    gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function(event) {
        var carousel = document.getElementById("mediaCarousel");
        var index = carousel.currentIndex;
        // how to pass this index to a function above?
         if( innerfunc ) innerfunc(index);
};
</script>
```

Make sure the top code executes first before the bottom one. If racing condition persists, you can check with,

> if( innerfunc ) innerfunc(index)

Hope it helps.